# Can we distill magic states with arbitrary angle $\theta$?

Tags: fault-tolerance, state-preparation, magic-states

There seems to be numerous work about the distillation protocol of the $T$-magic state
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+e^{i\pi/4}|1\rangle).
$$

Similarly, I am wondering if it is possible to distill a $\theta$-magic state
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+e^{i\theta}|1\rangle).
$$

Can we achieve it for arbitrary angle $\theta$? If not, what are the conditions for distillable $\theta$?

Comment: Could you comment a little bit more on allowed operations? For example, could I distill $|H\rangle$ magic states and use that those along with Clifford gates give universal quantum computation (and hence I can to any degree of accuracy rotate a qubit to your desired state)? Or is that off-limits?

Comment: @user196574 No strict requirements. Just make sure every step can be achieved (in principle) fault-tolerant.